# ArangoDB database directory locked

Tags: arangodb, nosql

When I execute

`sudo arangod` OR `sudo service arangodb start` within my home directory

I get the following messages

```
[2844] FATAL cannot start server: database directory is locked
[2867] FATAL cannot start server: database directory is locked
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, ArangoDB creates a lockfile in the database directory on startup to make sure that no two *arangod* processes concurrently work on the same database directory (most probably located in `/var/lib/arangodb/`).

Seeing the above error might have different reasons:

It may be possible that another ArangoDB instance is still running that uses the same database directory. In this case, the error message and refusal to start is properly justified. You can try to find out about other running `arangod` processes by issuing a command like `ps fax | grep arangod`.

If there is no ArangoDB running, the error might still occur if there is a file named `LOCK` in ArangoDB's database directory that is not readable or writable by the `arangod` process started. In this case, startup will be refused as well. This might be a privilege issue, but it is rather unlikely if you ran the command via `sudo`.

The final possibility is that the `flock()` call on the file `LOCK` failed for whatever reason. In this case the OS cannot guarantee that the file is locked exclusively for the `arangod` process just started. This would not prevent other `arangod` processes from trying to use the same database directory in parallel, which would be unsafe. So in this case, the server will also refuse to start. By the way, `flock` may not be implemented on all filesystems as it may be difficult to implement in a distributed fs. It should work for local filesystems however.

If you're 100 % sure no other `arangod` instance is running, there is no file privilege issue with the `LOCK` file and the error persists, you can try removing the `LOCK` file from the database directory manually and start the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked pretty nicely, I had another ArangoDB instance running, i'm working on the guesser project you guys have, thanks again